# Attribute Error when creating Pool using python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool, attributeerror, python-3.6

I'm trying to use the **multiprocessing.Pool.map** function in **Python 3.6** (using Windows 10) to speed up some code that otherwise takes an hour so to run.

I've split a large list of "*blobs*" into smaller lists and aim to use the mapping function to process a small numbers of *blobs* at a time.

I attempted to follow examples I found as closely as possible, but have encountered an unexpected error. The code I've written is as follows:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def function(arg):
    blob,image1,image2 = arg
    #does stuff to a blob using image1 and image2 get a string and an array
return [string,array]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4) 
    for(i in range(len(biglist))): #Each element is a smaller list which contains blobs
        blobcount = len(biglist[i])            
        print("Processed "+str(100*i/len(biglist)+"%")
        argslist = list(zip(biglist[i],[image1]*blobcount,[image2]*blobcount))
        results = pool.map(function,argslist)

        for i in range(len(results)):
            cataloguefile.write(results[i][0])      
    pool.close() 
    pool.join()
```

When I run the code, I get this error message on the pool creation line:

> ```
> AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__spec__'
> ```

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/f6b815487e9a3636cda457b44e0bc4b0.png) of the full console output.

Sorry if this is a silly error, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Your stack trace makes me a bit suspicious: You say it's Python 3 code (and the `multiprocessing` module is definitely Py3, since it is using `multiprocessing.context`), but it's being invoked via a `sitecustomize` wrapper using `execfile` (which doesn't exist in Py3). It might be some harmless Anaconda thing, but I'm suspicious. How are you running this?

Comment: Sorry, my screenshot cut off the top of the console. [Here](https://i.gyazo.com/1ebf8b4017ed7552534118383c728b30.png) is screenshot containing the top of the console. I'm running the file by hitting the run key in Spyder.

Comment: Have you tried running the file directly, outside the IDE? IDEs and the interactive interpreter in general can introduce some nasty issues with `multiprocessing` on Windows, since Windows simulates `fork`ing in a limited way that's heavily dependent on the exact structure of the `__main__` module, and running from within an existing Python session means you have two things that count as `__main__`, the interactive interpreter session itself, and whatever `runfile` is doing to pretend what it's running is `__main__`. It's [caused problems before](https://bugs.python.org/issue27487).

Comment: Thanks for the help, that stopped the problem! I've now set my IDE to execute in a dedicated console. Sadly, it seems in this case my implementation of multiprocessing actually made my code run slower than the standard map function (despite using 100% of my CPU whilst running). If you have any ideas as to why its not running as quickly as non multiprocessing code, I'd much appreciate it, though you have helped enormously already :)

Comment: Well, some basic stuff: First, don't pass an explicit `processes` argument to the pool. Let it allocate workers based on the number of cores you have available. Allocating fewer than you have means you don't parallelize as much, allocating more means your processes compete for cores, wasting time on context switches. It would also help to know what a typical `blobcount` is; if it's small, you'll reduce parallelism for the uneven number of tasks at each loop (if you can, you'd want to do a single huge `map`, not a bunch of small ones).

Comment: It also matters how big the arguments are, vs. how much work you're doing in the worker function. If the workers do 10 ms of work, but the arguments and return values require pickling and passing 10 MB of data (on my machine, pickling and unpickling a 10 MB `bytes` object seems to take over 9 ms, even without sending it over a pipe), then what you gain on parallelism is lost to IPC overhead. If the data is huge, using shared memory instead of sending data directly can help, if the data is small, but the work done is smaller, using a `chunksize` with `map` can sometimes help by batching work.

Comment: As a general note, you'd likely benefit from most exposure to/practice with Pythonic use of iterators/generators. You're forcing a lot of `list`s you don't need, and using a terrible anti-pattern (`for i in range(len(someseq)):` is basically always wrong, especially when you don't use `i` for anything but indexing `someseq`). Using iterators appropriately might allow you to get results more quickly, reduce memory use (both due to reduced temporaries and using `pool.imap` over `pool.map` so you write out results as available, rather than storing huge results until all are finished), etc.

Comment: I essentially fell into every single trap you mentioned. Following your advice, I reduced the function arguments and return down to a blob (numpy array of length 3) and a string (108 characters) respectively (from 180MB+ overall before :/). I reworked all the times I used for i in range(len(seq)) and am now using pool.imap instead (great tip!). After fixes, *blobcount* is 80 and takes 80 seconds to process with map and 60 with multiprocessing. I'd have expected a greater difference, given 1 blob takes 1 second to process (much more than IPC time?), but this is still great, thank-you v much :)

Comment: Are your return values similarly small? Remember, you pay the IPC cost for both arguments and return values, and you pay some of it twice (because you transmit it back over the pipe, then write it to a file in the main process). I can't give much more advice without more of the code aside from tweaks around the margins (e.g. if you're passing file names now instead of the image bytes, consider using `os.posix_fadvise` with `WILLNEED` for prefetch and/or using `mmap.mmap` to work with the file bytes without needing to `read` them in, especially if the file access is random/incomplete).